# Textbox.SelectionStart

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, selection

I'm trying to use the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties for a textbox. It is having no effect, but there are no errors either. It's actually part of a background worker ProgressChanged method, but I've tried the SelectionStart and SelectionLength in isolation in a test solution and it is the same.. nothing happens..

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Update the GUI as the music is playing
    textBox1.SelectionStart = ((int)e.UserState);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = (1);
}
```

Comment: I tried it with wpf and its the same.. compiles and runs without error but no effect

Comment: I just did a simple test with this.textBox1.SelectionStart = 3; and this.textBox1.SelectionLength = 1; in my Form_Load and it worked perfectly.  What exactly are you expecting to see that is not working for you?

Comment: grizzly, can you take a look at Edit3 to my answer? you might need to call Focus() on the box, the selection might not show if its not in focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code as is works fine for me (I'm assuming your BGW is started and you're calling `ReportProgress` of course).

My guess here is that your code is working for you too, but perhaps your TextBox doesn't have focus so you can't *see* the selected text.

If this is your problem, set the TextBox's [`HideSelection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection.aspx) to false.  This will allow the TextBox's selected text to display selected (highlighted) even if the TextBox doesn't have focus.

You can also query your TextBox's [SelectedText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) to get the control's selected text, even if it isn't displayed as such.

Comment: Did you mean to say False, for HideSelection?

Comment: Yes this hideselection = false actually works slightly better, when I was using the focus I would get some lag when hitting the cancel button

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that if you are running this code on the same thread which created the object (the GuiThread). A background worker is likely *not* the same thread as the one where the textbox was created.
You can ensure that you are using the GuiThread by calling Invoke on the control (which you can refer to with "this").

So.. do something like

this.Invoke().

You'll need to pass it a delegate, so move your textbox selection logic into a separate method, and then pass that method into the Invoke() call.

Edit:

Your code will probably look something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action<TextBox, int, int>(UpdateTextboxSelection), new object[] { textBox1, (int)e.UserState, 1 });
}

private void UpdateTextboxSelection(TextBox t, int start, int length)
{
    t.SelectionStart = start;
    t.SelectionLength = length;
    t.Focus(); // to make sure the box is in focus so that you see the selection
}
```

Edit 2: Note, I have not actually tried to see if this works, this is just a common problem that I have always had when wondering why certain UI things aren't doing anything, I notice I am running on a different thread and when I start using the GUI Thread it works.

Edit 3: I just ran a test. Make sure to Focus() on the textbox when you are done. It is possible that the text selection is being set as you are intending, but you don't see it because the box is not in focus.

Comment: I dont think  thats the problem.. For example if I put this...       label6.Text = e.UserState.ToString();  In my progresschanged method it has no problem changing the label text which is in the same form. Also thanks!

Comment: @grizzly_beer I think Jay's solution hits the spot and it's a better approach than explicitly calling Focus like I am saying here.

Comment: Yeah I have just tried that and I agree, thanks again! was getting some lag on hitting cancel button with the focus